# Kotlin, scan QR and show data simultaneously

Tags: kotlin

I develop a Kotlin app to transfer data between devices.
The app must not use any kind of wireless/wired/bluetooth connection, completely offline.

The idea is to put two devices in front each other, one device will show the data to the second device by QR codes. at the same time the second device reads the QR and response by showing an ACK QR.

My question is, if it is possible to scan QR data while showing another different QR on the screen with Kotlin and how.

Comment: I would say scanning a QR-code is a wireless connection...

Comment: I meant without Internet, Bluetooth, NFC…